# venting a range hood outside on our cedar cabin

Tags: hvac, exterior

i need to vent our range hood outside on our cedar cabin and it is on the front of the house we would like it to be as inconspicuous as possible I can not find a vent that would work well with a cedar cabin

Answer (score 2):

As long as the outside part focuses the air down [like this one](https://www.homedepot.com/p/3-25-in-x-10-in-Rectangular-Wall-Vent-WVA3-25X10/100396974) instead of straight out [like this one](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Speedi-Products-4-in-Louvered-Plastic-Exhaust-Hood-with-Snap-Ring-EX-HLFW-04/202907371), you can build a wood enclosure around it. It will still be an "add on" but if you stain it to match the surrounding area it shouldn't be so obvious and won't look so out of place.

Answer (score 0):

@kristi okane. Is there a cabinet above your stove in which a pipe could be run up above ceiling and out and down through soffits or eave?